# How does one add an email to an automation in Sendgrid?

Tags: sendgrid

In Sendgrid, I have a live automation of welcome emails.

I need to add a second email to that series but I do not see the option to do so.

Can someone guide where it might be available?
In the [sendgrid Help-center](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/getting-started-with-automation), it states the following:

> To add more emails to this automated series, click **Add an Email**.

However, I am not able to find the option of 'Add an Email' on the UI

[image: UI of Sendgrid]

Answer (score 2):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Once you set an Automation live you can no longer add emails to it, though you can edit the existing email content.

To add a new email to an Automation, you can [duplicate the Automation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/getting-started-with-automation#duplicate-an-automation) (under "Automation options") then add the new emails. Once you are happy, you can set the new Automation live and disable the old one.

Comment: It is quite disappointing that you can't rearrange or insert emails to an automation once it has gone live. I just filed a support ticket with SendGrid and the response is still the same. You have to duplicate the automation and create a new contact list or segment that receives the new contacts. The old list/segment must no longer receive new contacts, to avoid duplicate emails. Pretty half baked solution if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to disable and then duplicate the automation before you can add an email. However, good luck trying to reorder emails on the duplicated automation, you can't, which is tragic .

SendGrid has one of the worst UI/UX for a company of its size. We have been using them for years and are finally tired enough to leave them, every person on our team finds it so tiring to use.